# echo variable from if statement of other function

Tags: php

```
   public function Validate($username,$password) {

   $stmp = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? and password = ?");
   $stmp->bindParam(1, $username);
   $stmp->bindParam(2, $password);
   $stmp->execute();

   $this->session = $username;

   if($stmp->rowCount() == 1) {

     $this->session = $username; 

   }

}

public function LoggedIn() {
   echo $this->session;
}
```

So I have these 2 functions, and I want to be able to `echo $this->session` inside the `LoggedIn()`, although it seems impossible right now as the variable is inside an if statement. It works if I put the variable out of the statement. Any suggestions or Idea on how I can do this properly?

Comment: Isn't it because when `$stmp->rowCount()` is different from 1 then `$username` is null?

Comment: call the function and return the value

Answer (score 1):

This is telling you that $stmp->rowCount() is not equal to 1.  Do the following:

1. Run the query manually in your database (eg: using phpMyAdmin).  Do you see rows?  If not, there's your problem.  No rows are matching your query.
2. If you do get rows back then before your if statement do a var_dump of $stmp->rowCount().  If it returns 0, you want to check the values of $username and $password by var_dumping those.  If it returns greater than 1 it means there are duplicate rows in your table.  If it returns something else like null, it might be the wrong function to use. In that case check the documentation for the database package you are using.